# h:commandButton action in ui:fragment sometimes not doing action

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Using JSF 2.1

We have a form that encapsulates blocks of search results.  Each block has a "Delete" button that talks to the View scoped backing and removes the block (from a Session scoped bean).

Visually something like this:

```
  -- group
    -- block (delete button)
      -- search result
    -- block 
      -- search result
    ...
```

When the last block is deleted the entire group disappears.

Anyways.  The follow implementation of a delete works fine:

```
<h:commandButton 
  styleClass="delete"
  action="#{backing.taBortFranTrafflista(sokning)}"
  value="#{backing.getText('trafflista.taBort')}"
  onclick="return confirm('#{backing.getText('FR100', sokning.sokbegrepp, backing.aktuelltAntalTraffar(sokning))}');"
  rendered="#{backing.javascriptEnabled}"
  disabled="#{commons.trafflistaLast}">
    <f:ajax render="@form" />
</h:commandButton>
```

However, the following implementation with a confirmation do in JQuery works but NOT with the last search result whereby the action (assigned to the h:commandButton) is never called:

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{backing.javascriptEnabled}">
  <div id="dialog#{sokning.hashCode()}" title="Ta bort" class="dialog">
    <p>#{backing.getText('FR100', sokning.sokbegrepp, backing.aktuelltAntalTraffar(sokning))}</p>
    <h:commandButton 
      styleClass="delete dialog-button"
      action="#{backing.taBortFranTrafflista(sokning)}"
      value="#{backing.getText('trafflista.taBort')}"   
      onclick="closeDialog('dialog#{sokning.hashCode()}')"              
      disabled="#{commons.trafflistaLast}">
      <f:ajax render="@form" onerror="ajaxError"/>
    </h:commandButton>
    <input 
       type="submit" 
       data="dialog#{sokning.hashCode()}" 
       class="closeDialog dialog-button" 
       value="#{backing.getText('trafflista.avbryt')}" />
  </div>
  <ui:fragment rendered="#{not commons.trafflistaLast}">
    <input 
       type="submit" 
       data="dialog#{sokning.hashCode()}" 
       class="delete showDialog" 
       value="#{backing.getText('trafflista.taBort')}" />
  </ui:fragment>
  <ui:fragment rendered="#{commons.trafflistaLast}">
    <input 
       type="submit" 
       class="delete showDialog" 
       value="#{backing.getText('trafflista.taBort')}" 
       disabled="disabled"/>
  </ui:fragment>
</ui:fragment>
```

Comment: Side note, the problem (with the ui:fragment implementation) does not happen when there is only one search result block in a group.  Weird.

Comment: Some strange thing I see in your given code that don't like very much. First `#{backing.getText('trafflista.taBort')}`. Well, getters are getters in java, and are used for properties. They have no argument. So you should rename that method to something like `textForArg(String arg)`. Second thing, is your button supposed to cause ajax or whole-submit behaviour? `h:commandButton` is designed to behave as non-ajax when `action` specified. However, you're making kind of mix of both of them. Have a look at the docs about the tag: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkace.html

Comment: get/set syntax noted.  Read the documentation about the **listener** attribute in the f:ajax rather than in the h:commandButton action.  Has no effect, both cases a partial/ajax request.

Comment: putting a **ui:fragment** around the **h:commandButton** in the working implementation and moving the rendered attribute to the fragment yields a working result.

Comment: Problem does not arise if the blocks are removed from last to first.

Comment: With the **ui:fragment** implementation if **faces-redirect=true** is added to the outcome of the called method then it works ONLY if the action is defined to the **h:commandButton** and not the **f:ajax** directive.

Comment: Which JSF impl are you dealing with?

Comment: According to [Jboss EAP information](https://access.redhat.com/site/articles/112673) it is a RedHat implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Reason **faces-redirect=true** works is that DOM components inside the form match up with the server representation.  The JQuery dialog was rendered outside the form at the bottom of the page.  Doing a render equal **@all** solved the problem.  Another solution was to render the dialog inside the form.